# Load .npy file with np.load progress bar

Tags: python, numpy, progress-bar

I have a really large .npy file (previously saved with np.save) and I am loading it with:

```
np.load(open('file.npy'))
```

Is there any way to see the progress of the loading process? I know tqdm and some other libraries for monitoring the progress but don't how to use them for this problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far I am aware, `np.load` does not provide any callbacks or hooks to monitor progress. However, there is a work around which may work: `np.load` can open the file as a memory-mapped file, which means the data stays on disk and is loaded into memory only on demand. We can abuse this machinery to manually copy the data from the memory mapped file into actual memory using a loop whose progress can be monitored.

Here is an example with a crude progress monitor:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.randn(8096, 4096)
np.save('file.npy', x)

blocksize = 1024  # tune this for performance/granularity

try:
    mmap = np.load('file.npy', mmap_mode='r')
    y = np.empty_like(mmap)
    n_blocks = int(np.ceil(mmap.shape[0] / blocksize))
    for b in range(n_blocks):
        print('progress: {}/{}'.format(b, n_blocks))  # use any progress indicator
        y[b*blocksize : (b+1) * blocksize] = mmap[b*blocksize : (b+1) * blocksize]
finally:
    del mmap  # make sure file is closed again

assert np.all(y == x)
```

Plugging any progress-bar library into the loop should be straight forward.

I was unable to test this with exceptionally large arrays due to memory constraints, so I can't really tell if this approach has any performance issues.

Comment: This is great.  Wondering if we might need to adjust the ending index to avoid going beyond the bounds of the array in case `blocksize` isn't a multiple of `mmap.shape[0]`?   e.g. `start, end = b*blocksize, min( (b+1) * blocksize, mmap.shape[0] )`, and then slice on `[start:end]` ?

Comment: @sh37211 Well observed, I had to look it up again to be sure :) Python's sequence types define that slices should be automatically truncated [see docs, note 4](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange). I think numpy follows the same convention so we don't need to check.